# python detecting mouse over navigation widget

Tags: python

I want to be able to detect when the mouse is over any of these icons and the navigation widgets so I can pass through events through my modal operator.  I know how to get mouse position, detect if it's in a particular area/region etc.

I don't know all the preferences and settings that can allow me to calculate their width, height and locations.

[image]

Here is all the digging I have done.

I can detect if the navigation gizmo is there or not
[image]

https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_gizmo_navigate.c$45

```
/* Offset from screen edge. */
#define GIZMO_OFFSET_FAC 1.2f
/* Size of main icon. */
#define GIZMO_SIZE 80
/* Factor for size of smaller button. */
#define GIZMO_MINI_FAC 0.35f
/* How much mini buttons offset from the primary. */
#define GIZMO_MINI_OFFSET_FAC 0.38f

enum {
  GZ_INDEX_MOVE = 0,
  GZ_INDEX_ROTATE = 1,
  GZ_INDEX_ZOOM = 2,

  /* just buttons */
  /* overlaps GZ_INDEX_ORTHO (switch between) */
  GZ_INDEX_PERSP = 3,
  GZ_INDEX_ORTHO = 4,
  GZ_INDEX_CAMERA = 5,

  GZ_INDEX_TOTAL = 6,
};
```

To me this says there is a 1.2 pixel offset from the screen edge
the rotation gizmo is 80 pixels
the smaller gizmos are .35 the size of the rotation gizmo (28 pixels
I don't know what the .38f offset is, perhaps a vertical offset?

There are some clues in the drawing
https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_draw.c$1469

```
#Sample with code
def should_pass_through(self, context, event):
    if context.area.type != "VIEW_3D":
        return False

    #first, check outside of area
    if event.mouse_x < context.area.x: return False
    if event.mouse_y < context.area.y: return False
    if event.mouse_x > context.area.x + context.area.width: return False
    if event.mouse_y > context.area.y + context.area.height: return False

    #make sure we are in the window region, not the header, tools or UI
    for reg in context.area.regions:
        if in_region(reg, event.mouse_x, event.mouse_y) and reg.type != "WINDOW":
            return False

    #check panel open
    #check visibility preferences for gizmos
    #get icon and button width and height
    #do math to figure out if we are over them
    #if so allow pass through and flag
```